# Error when querying Hibernate entities

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I have two Hibernate entities as below with relationship between them and I am having problem querying them.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tdbs", catalog="dbcreator")
public class DB extends DBEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="usr", referencedColumnName="usr", nullable=false)
    private User user;


@Entity
@Table(name="tusers",catalog="dbcreator", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames="email"))
@XmlRootElement(name = "User")
public class User extends DBEntity {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="usr", unique=true, nullable=false, length=30)
    private String usr;
```

What I want to query for is to get the list of DB entities that are linked to particular user ("user" variable holds actual user name). I use below query:

```
List<DB> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                "from DB p where p.user=:usrId").setString("usrId", user).list();
```

However this is giving me some strange error as below. Anyone has an idea how to get this sorted?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dbcreator.persistence.hibernate.model.User_$$_javassist_5 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4419)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1017)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:944)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:917)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2548)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2534)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2359)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1194)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at com.dbcreator.persistence.impl.DatabaseDAO.getDBList(DatabaseDAO.java:30)
```

Comment: what type is `user` ? You should use `setParameter` instead of `setString` also you have to proper override `equals` and `hashCode`

Comment: user is actually of type String. Can that be string since the ID column of User table is string? Do I need to put an entity type there (i.e. User)? Because I think I tried that and got the same error.

Comment: if you put an String, then you should put `p.user.name` instead of `p.user`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be as follows:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
createQuery("from DB p where p.user.usr=:usrId").setParameter("usrId", user)
```

**Sidenote**

Consistent and meaningful naming would improve readability. My personal choice would have been:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
createQuery("from DB db where db.user.usr=:usr").setParameter("usr", userString)
```

And maybe the `User.usr` member variable should be called something like `User.id` or `User.name` depending on what it actually represents.